# Connect computer to external hard-drive using ethernet port

Tags: networking, external-hard-drive, thunderbolt

I have an old [Seagate Central](http://www.seagate.com/files/www-content/support-content/external-products/seagate-central/en-us/seagate-central-user-guide-us.pdf) external hard-drive which has a USB-A and Ethernet port.  It's meant to be connected to a router and accessed remotely; with the USB-A port used for chaining an additional drive.

I don't have access to connect the drive to my router though and I don't have a USB-A to USB-A cable at the moment to try that.  I do have an Ethernet to Thunderbolt adapter so I've tried running an ethernet cable directly to my computer from the drive.  In the network settings I activated the port and it immediately self-assigned itself an IP.

[image]

It showed up in the Finder sidebar but any attempt to open it in Finder fails.

[image]

I'm thinking that perhaps the port configuration is not correct or I need to be using a [crossover-cable](/questions/tagged/crossover-cable) (I have some spare connectors I can swap out and make it a cross-over cable but not gonna do it unless I'm sure that's the problem).

Comment: You need to configure the drive. If it's configured to get its IP address using DHCP, you need to configure a DHCP server on your machine. Having *your* interface configured to DHCP will only work if the drive is a DHCP server, which seems very unlikely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to David's comment I figured out how to make it work.

I first activated the DHCP service within OSX using the command `sudo /bin/launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/bootps.plist`

Once that was done, in the network system preferences I set it to manual and filled in the fields with default values.

Then it worked.

[image]

Comment: To disable the DHCP service `sudo /bin/launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/bootps.plist`